# How can I force my wifi to connect to a G-band channel?

Tags: wifi, debugging

I'm trying to debug a buggy wireless card and would like to force my Linux computer to connect using one of the g-band channels.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

'G-Band channels' are the same as b/n. If you want to connect using G only you could use iwconfig like so `iwconfig eth0 freq 2.422G`

Comment: I've disabled NetworkManager, but whenever I run this command (on the `wlan0` interface), I get `SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy.`  Is there a way to find out what's keeping it busy?

Comment: I believe you just don't have permission to execute that command. I found adding "sudo" in front worked for me "sudo iwconfig wlan0 freq 2.412" executed without that error.