# How do you stop NetworkManager in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome3, networkmanager

I'm trying to force my wifi card to connect over the G-band as per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77851/34796).  However, when I run `iwconfig`, I am told the resource is busy:

```
[root@Eiger ~]# iwconfig wlan0 freq 2.422G
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Device or resource busy
```

I'm pretty sure this is because NetworkManager is running.  However, when I try to stop it, it just respawns again.  I've tried stopping it through `systemctl stop` and `kill`.  How can I permanently turn off NetworkManager in Gnome 3?

Comment: Try disabling it too: `systemctl disable NetworkManager`.

Comment: This only affect whether the process is started upon boot.  Is there away to turn it off without rebooting?

Comment: How about "chkconfig Networkmanager off"

Comment: @drs - try this: stop & disable also `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`. After disabling both, backup then remove this file: `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.service`. Finally, open `/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service` and comment out: `Alias=dbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.service` (e.g. `#Alias=...`).

Comment: @don_crissti Nice.  That did it.

Comment: Unfortunately the device is still reported as busy..

Comment: @don_crissti I've taken it down with `ifdown` and tried killing `wpa_supplicant`, `dhclient`, `dhcpcd`, `hostapd` and it's still being reported busy.